# The catch in proving that a singleton is a Borel set?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, borel-measures

Let $\Omega= (0,1]$. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the collection of all open interval in $(0,1]$.
By open interval in $(0,1]$ I mean any interval of the form $(a,b)$, where $a\geq 0$ and $b\leq 1$.
Let $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ be the smallest sigma-algebra that contains $\mathcal{C}$. We call this sigma-algebra a Borel-sigma algebra. Now, let us we have to prove that the singleton $\{0.7\}$ is in $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$. In order to prove it, we use the following result:
\begin{equation}
\{0.7\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big[(0.7-1/n, 0.7+1/n)\cap(0,1]\Big].
\end{equation}
The above result is based on the fact that
\begin{equation}
(0.7-1/n, 0.7+1/n)\cap(0,1]\in\mathcal{C}\in\sigma(\mathcal{C}), \mbox{for}\ n=2,3,4...
\end{equation}
Therefore the intersection of $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big[(0.7-1/n, 0.7+1/n)\cap(0,1]\Big]$ would be contained in $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$.

However, here is the catch, for $n=2$, we have
\begin{equation}
(0.7-1/n, 0.7+1/n)\cap(0,1]= (0.2, 1.2)\cap(0,1]=(0.2, 1]\notin \mathcal{C}
\end{equation}
Therefore the quantity $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big[(0.7-1/n, 0.7+1/n)\cap(0,1]\Big]$ does not have to be contained in $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$.

Now, can anybody help me to figure out how my argument is not valid?

Comment: I wonder about your notion of "open interval in $(0,1]$." Maybe you should write it out explicitly, at the beginning. (Write your definition of this concept.) Welcome to Math Stack.

Comment: The comment of [311411](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/688046/311411) is key. $(0,1]$ is an open subset of $(0,1]$ for the relative topology. It is also an interval for the relative and global topologies.

Comment: @311411; By open interval in $(0,1]$ I mean any open interval $(a,b)$ which is contained in $(0,1]$. Is my notion wrong? Please clarify!

Comment: @311411 ; I have edited my question as exactly as you suggested me.

Comment: So if $n=2$ is a problem, take $\displaystyle \bigcap_{n=3}^\infty$ instead.

Comment: @RobertIsrael ; It doesn't help because it can happen again for $n=3$ and for any other singleton.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net ; Do you mean (0.2, 1] is an open interval in (0, 1]? If yes, then how?

Comment: For any singleton $\{x\}\subset (0,1)$ there is an $n_0$ such that for all $n\ge n_0$ the  open intervals $(x-1/n,x+1/n)$ are subsets of $(0,1]$.

Comment: A detour: $\{1\}=(0,1)^c$ when we look at $(0,1]$ as the universe. And $\sigma$-algebras are closed under complementation. So $\{1\}\in\mathcal C$ and consequently $(a,1]=(a,1)\cup\{1\}\in\mathcal C$ for every $a\in(0,1)$.

Comment: @KurtG. ; Can you prove it?

Comment: Take $n_0$ to be the max of $\lceil 1/x\rceil$ and $\lceil 1/(1-x)\rceil$ . @drhab : Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

**Understanding the topology (this part is to address the confusion in the comments under the original question):** Let us first make sure we have the right notion of open intervals in $\Sigma = \left(0,1\right]$. Let us assume that $\mathbb{R}$ is endowed with the standard topology $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}}$ generated by open intervals, which are in $\mathbb{R}$ defined as $(a,b)$, with $a < b$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. This also seems like the topology you would like to work with and thus it seems like a natural choice. Let us assume furtermore that $\Omega = \left(0,1 \right] \subset \mathbb{R}$ is endowed with the **subspace topology** defined as
$$\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{\Omega}} := \{\Omega \cap U: U \in \mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}} \}.$$
As @311411 and @mathcounterexamples.net already pointed out, $\left(0,1\right]$ is an open interval in $\left(0,1\right]$ since it lies in the subspace topology and since it is an interval. Even more so: any interval of the form $\left(a,1\right]$ with $0<a<1$ is open in $\left(0,1\right]$ since they can be written as $\left(a,1\right] = \Omega \cap (0,2)$ and since  $(0,2) \in \mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}}$. However, any interval of the form $\left(a,b\right]$ with $0<a<b<1$ is not open since it is not open in $\mathbb{R}$ and since it can be directly compared to open sets in $\mathbb{R}$, namely $\Omega\cap \left(a,b\right] = \left(a,b\right]$ (likewise with the square- and standard bracket reversed). This means that all the other intervals in $\left(0,1\right]$ can only be called open if they are of the form $(a,b)$ with $0 < a < b < 1$, just as you are used to in $\mathbb{R}$ (check for yourself that this is indeed the case by checking that they lie in the subspace topology).

**Now proving that a singleton is a Borel set:** Once you have established the right notion of a topology on $\left(0,1\right]$ and given that we work with the standard definition of intervals, we can now have a understanding of this collection $\mathcal{C}$: the intervals $(a,b)$ with $0<a<b<1$ and the intervals $\left(a,1\right]$ with $0<a<1$. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $\left(0,1\right]$ can now indeed be defined as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$.

Then now showing that any singleton $\{x\}$ lies in $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ comes down to showing that we can find the right (infinite) combination of sets in $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ that generate $\{x\}$, according to the definition of $\sigma$-algebras. As @Kurt G pointed out, we can always find $n_{0}$ such that for any $n \geq n_0$ we have that
$$\left(x - \frac{1}{n}, x + \frac{1}{n}\right) \in \sigma(\mathcal{C}),$$
namely:
$$n_0 = \lceil \frac{1}{\max\{ \frac{x}{2}, \frac{1-x}{2} \}} \rceil,$$
(this is really just solving inequalities, I leave this to the OP for now).
Now by definition of the $\sigma$-algebra we can find that
$$\{x\} = \bigcap_{n\geq n_0} \left(x - \frac{1}{n}, x + \frac{1}{n}\right) \in \sigma(\mathcal{C}).$$

If you see any mistakes, please let me know.

Comment: OP's issue seems to me not about topology, but about a inaccuracy in their understanding of sigma algebras. We don't need to show that intersections belong to the generating family $\mathcal{C}$, which I think is what threw OP off.

Comment: @Snoop: I agree, and I was going to write a comment along these lines, but then I saw your comment.

Comment: @Nelus : What does the $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}}$ represents?

Comment: @Nelus127 : According to your notion of $\mathcal{C}$ the set $(0, 0.5) \notin \mathcal{C}$?

Comment: @Snoop and Dave L. Renfro, thanks for your comments. Indeed, the question is about the $\sigma$-algebra, but since there also seemed to be confusion about the topology in the comments under that question, I decided to also address that. But I will make an edit in this answer to make that clear.

Comment: @RobinKurtz, according to the above notion of $\mathcal{C}$ we still have $(0,0.5) \in \mathcal{C}$ since $(0, 0.5)$ is an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ and since $\Omega \cap (0, 0.5) = (0, 0.5)$. You can still mostly understand $\mathcal{C}$ as just the collection of open subsets in $\left(0,1\right]$ as you would do intuitively, but I just made sure to define the notion of an open interval in $\left(0,1\right]$ as neatly as possible, since that is what you base the definition of $\mathcal{C}$ on.

Comment: Also, $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}}$ is the standard topology on $\mathcal{R}$ generated by open intervals, as stated in the beginning of the answer.

Comment: @Snoop also, I agree that we do not have to show that the intersection belongs to the generating family $\mathcal{C}$, which would also be false (since the intersection is equal to $\{x\}$, if we are talking about the same intersection.) However, you do have to make sure that the intervals that you use in your intersection also lie in the Borel $\sigma$-algbera on $\left(0,1\right]$ generated by $\mathcal{C}$, which is in this case very easy since the intervals $\left( x - \frac{1}{n}, x + \frac{1}{n} \right)$ for $n \geq n_0$ lie in the generating collection $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: And to be complete: we can say that $\left( x - \frac{1}{n}, x + \frac{1}{n} \right) \in \mathcal{C}$ for $n \geq n_0$ since $\left( x - \frac{1}{n}, x + \frac{1}{n} \right)$ are open in $\mathbb{R}$ under the standard definitions on $\mathbb{R}$ (that is to say $\left( x - \frac{1}{n}, x + \frac{1}{n} \right)$ are intervals and $\left( x - \frac{1}{n}, x + \frac{1}{n} \right) \in \mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}}$) and since $\left( x - \frac{1}{n}, x + \frac{1}{n} \right) \cap \left(0,1\right] = \left( x - \frac{1}{n}, x + \frac{1}{n} \right)$, we have by definition that they lie in $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: But this is way more elaborate than one would normally be when proving that $\{x\}$ lies in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\left(0,1\right]$. In most cases you keep the rigour of the topology in the back of your head but you do not write it down.